# Add a Radio Button and Do an SQL Command in PHP

Tags: php, html

Good Afternoon.
I just want to ask a Question but before that let me explain it to all of you in a best way I can

As of now I have the ff.

```
Database: Election2016
Table: Candidate_Info
Fields: CandidateName and Position
```

As of now here is my code and the output of this is Show the Data in HTML Table

```
<html>
    <center>
        <font size="2" face = "century gothic">
        <?php
            $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "election2016");
            // Check connection
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
            }

            $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM candidate_info");
            echo "<table border='1'>
            <tr>
                <th>CandidateName</th>
                <th>Position</th>
            </tr>";
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['CandidateName'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Position'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";
            mysqli_close($con);
        ?>
    </center>
    </font>
</html>
```

And my target here is how can I attach a Radio Button to it? next to it? Attach a Radio Button in every row populated.

and my next target here which is very tricky to me is that when I press a button how will the data i choose with the corresponding radiobutton will be saved?

Example:

```
Candidate Name
Student 1
Position
President
Radio Button 1 (Example name of the Radio Button)
```

I selected RadioButton1 and press button "Save" how will Student 1 and President will be saved in a  table?

I hope you understand TYIA

Answer (score 0):

You should create one **primary_key** field to the table **Candidate_Info** as **CandidateId** with Auto increment and not null.

To add radio button

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><input type='radio' name='candidateid' value='".$row['CandidateId']."' />" . $row['CandidateName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Position'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

while select the radio button and saving the form you should get the candidate record as

> SELECT * FROM candidate_info WHERE CandidateId=**[CandidateId]**

replace the **[CandidateId]** with the selected radio button value.

After executing the above query you will be getting the selected candidate info, then you can save it.

Comment: Pls see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36231616/undefined-index-inside-a-while-php?noredirect=1#comment60095330_36231616

Comment: see my answer - [stackoverflow.com/a/36232518/6097363](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36232518/6097363)