# Undefined Index inside a While PHP

Tags: php

I get an error of Undefined index, what is the reason?

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<tr>";

        echo "<td>" . $row['CandidateName'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Position'] . "</td>";
         echo "<td><input type='radio' name='candidateid' value='".$row['candidateID']."' >";
      echo "<td>" . $row['NumberofVotes'] . "</td>";
        $candidateid=$row['CandidateID'];

    }
```

Here is the error

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [CandidateID] => 1 [1] => Jejomar Binay [CandidateName] => Jejomar Binay [2] => President [Position] => President [3] => [NumberofVotes] => ) Array ( [0] => 2 [CandidateID] => 2 [1] => Mar Roxas [CandidateName] => Mar Roxas [2] => President [Position] => President [3] => 1 [NumberofVotes] => 1 )
```

I will show you now the whole code and the its working now, my output here is to add 1 in number of votes when the radio button is working. it has no error but when i selected the first radio button it only updates the second data.

```
<html>
        <center>
        <font size="2" face = "century gothic">
        <?php
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","election2016");
        // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM candidate_info");
        echo "<table border='1'>
        <tr>
        <th>Candidate Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Vote</th>
        <th>Number of Votes</th>
        </tr>";
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<tr>";

            echo "<td>" . $row['CandidateName'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Position'] . "</td>";
             echo "<td><input type='radio' name='candidateid' value='".$row['CandidateID']."' >";
          echo "<td>" . $row['NumberofVotes'] . "</td>";
            $candidateID=$row['CandidateID'];

        }
        echo "</table>";
        mysqli_close($con);
        ?>

        <br>
        <br>
        <form method = "post" action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
     <input type="text" name="candidateid" value="<?php echo $candidateID;?>">
         <input name = "update" type = "submit" id = "update" value = "update">
        </form>
        </center>
        </font>
        </html>
        <?php
                 if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
                    $dbhost = 'localhost';
                    $dbuser = 'root';
                    $dbpass = '';
 $candidateid = $_POST['candidateid'];
                    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

                    if(! $conn ) {
                       die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
                    }

                    $candidateid = $_POST['candidateid'];


                    $sql = "UPDATE candidate_info SET numberofvotes = 1 WHERE candidateid = '$candidateid'" ;
                    mysql_select_db('election2016');
                    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

                    if(! $retval ) {
                       die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
                    }
                    echo "Updated data successfully\n";

                    mysql_close($conn);
                 }
        ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: print_r($row); what result is display and show thats result

Comment: Pls see the edited one

Comment: `echo "<td><input type='radio' name='candidateid' value='".$row['CandidateID']."' >";` try this @AlexiusjoeCoronel

Comment: pls see the new edited one.

Comment: @MayankVadiya pls see my new post

Comment: Paste The Error or tell the line no in which error coming.

Comment: @NanaPartykar sir theres no error but the value of radio button did not transfer on hidden textbox

Comment: I am not able to see any hidden textbox in your given code.

Comment: @NanaPartykar im sorry i already change it with the text this one ` <input type="text" name="candidateid" value="<?php echo $candidateID;?>">`

Comment: Do One Favour. Please Provide **correct** `column name` of `candidate_info` table.

Comment: Sir my table name Candidate_info with fields of candidateid,candidatename,position and numberofvotes

Comment: Sir is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes. Wait for my answer.

Comment: All column name are correct ? Means `candidatename` is right or `CandidateName` ? @AlexiusjoeCoronel

Comment: sir i think thats right because i dont get any error on that, sir i just want to make it simple and this one will close my prob. how can i transfer the radio button value in the textbox

Comment: Let me ask you one question. First of all, all `candidateid` coming through while loop. So, you will get the very last `candidateid` in your textbox. Tell me your idea behind this. What you exactly want. You want to select the candidate and update the `numberofvotes` for selected candidate or what. Please elaborate

Comment: Sir your correct when i click the radio button the number of votes will increment by 1 when i press the button update so what am i doing is to pass the value of candidate id in the textbox so it will update my database.

Comment: Any idea or code sir that you might give will be appreciated. by the way sir the candiateid is primarykey,not null and auto increment. the only output i want is to select the the candidate using radio button and when i press the  update it will add 1 and if other one votes it will add another 1 so it will become 2 and so on

Comment: Ok. You want to select multiple candidate at a time to increase number of votes. Please clear my doubt. As i see, you have asked too many questions regarding this problem in stack overflow. So, please be clear. Clear my doubt.

Comment: Here is my only goal Sir, I will only select 1 Candidate and Add a vote in database Sir. Example when I select the Radio Button of the first student his or her votes will increment by one in the database thats all sir

Comment: @NanaPartykar Sir this okay for you? to help me?

Comment: Sorry for being late to answer @AlexiusjoeCoronel. I was in meeting. Go through my points and use my updated code. Any question. *Feel free to ask*. All The Best. `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field "candidateid" should be integer data type, but you are enclosed this field value with **''(single quotes)** in the update query?

```
$sql = "UPDATE candidate_info SET numberofvotes = 1 WHERE candidateid = '$candidateid'";
```

if it is an integer datatype then you should remove the single quote

```
$sql = "UPDATE candidate_info SET numberofvotes = 1 WHERE candidateid = $candidateid";
```

and in MySQL every field names are case sensitive, so as you told the field names are

> candidateid, candidatename, position, numberofvotes

so, you should use these names when you retrieving the values as well

```
    <?php
             if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
                $dbhost = 'localhost';
                $dbuser = 'root';
                $dbpass = '';
                $candidateid = $_POST['candidateid'];
                $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

                if(! $conn ) {
                   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
                }

                $candidateid = $_POST['candidateid'];


                $sql = "UPDATE candidate_info SET numberofvotes = numberofvotes + 1 WHERE candidateid = '$candidateid'" ;
                mysql_select_db('election2016');
                $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

                if(! $retval ) {
                   die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
                }
                echo "Updated data successfully\n";

                mysql_close($conn);
             }
    ?>
<html>
    <center>
    <font size="2" face = "century gothic">
    <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","election2016");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM candidate_info");
    ?>
    <form method = "post" action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
    <?php
    echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>Candidate Name</th>
    <th>Position</th>
    <th>Vote</th>
    <th>Number of Votes</th>
    </tr>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['candidatename'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['position'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td><input type='radio' name='candidateid' value='".$row['candidateid']."' >";
        echo "<td>" . $row['numberofvotes'] . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>

    <br>
    <br>
    <input name = "update" type = "submit" id = "update" value = "update">
    </form>
    </center>
    </font>
    </html>
```

Comment: it works great bit why i cant transfer radiobutton value in the textbox so i can update it

Comment: Why do you want to transfer the value to the textbox?

Comment: You can directly start the form tag before table tag then you can automatically get the selected radio button value after submitting the form.

Comment: my goal here is when I press the radiobutton the numbervotes will increase by one, can you help me  with that?

Comment: Wow TY so much its a big help but it only adds 1 how can i increase it? i mean two persons vote the same candidate how it will increase by 1 and save in database?

Comment: in that case you can update your update query like `$sql = "UPDATE candidate_info SET numberofvotes = numberofvotes + 1 WHERE candidateid = '$candidateid'" ;`

Comment: it works so great TY so much but i think theres an error like for example i have 2 data and i select the 1st one the second data will be updated and theres an instance that the past command will execute something like that. I will approve now your code. TY so much this is my last error @Thiyagesan

Comment: If I understand your problem, then my guess is correct, You should move your PHP code which is below to the </html> tag to the top of entire code, so that your update query will update before displaying the form. Then you will get the updated result too.

Comment: What do you mean sir? at the top of <html>? the whole code of inside the php tag?

Comment: Sir its done, All I want to say is thank you so so much! :)

Comment: Sir its ok now but when i refresh it the sql query works i mean its updating.

Comment: To avoid resubmitting the form you can reload the page after completing the update query like this `header('Location: [CurrentFileName]');` replace **[CurrentFileName]** with your file name.

Comment: Sir where i will put that?

Comment: After `$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );` line but you will not get that success message, then you can remove the code `if(! $retval ) {
                   die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
                }
                echo "Updated data successfully\n";`

Comment: Sir its ok now, A very big Thank you so much

Comment: Hi Sir its an honor for me to be helped by you ahmmm sir I have a new question pls see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36233712/bar-graph-using-the-data-from-mysql-database @NanaPartykar

Answer (score 1):

there is no key in your array `$row` as `'candidateid'` please do `var_dump($row);` and see what is the key name, or if these are just same as your column name in your DB table, check the name of it.

Comment: Sir pls see the edited post there is a new error and i try what you said

Comment: @AlexiusjoeCoronel change `$row['candidateid']` to `$row['CandidateID']` remove var_dump now

Comment: you did not change the key in input element, change `echo "<td><input type='radio' name='candidateid' value='".$row['candidateID']."' >";` with `echo "<td><input type='radio' name='candidateid' value='".$row['CandidateID']."' >";`

Comment: @AlexiusjoeCoronel so you are now changing the question of what was your error at first? why not just tell us what to code and we can do YOUR WORK?

Comment: Sit thanks for the help but i think youve done so much for me, thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

**Points To Be Noted :**

1. No Need to create separate `<form></form>` for sending `candidateid` for updating `numberofvotes`.
2. If you are submitting in same page then avoid multiple database connection.
3. Your database table `candidate_info` field name is not matching with what you wrote in `<table><tr></tr></table>`. So, use exact column name what is there in database table.
4. Put your complete `<table></table>` inside `<form></form>`.
5. Since you are looking for single candidate value to get get updated, so `radio` button is helpful. If multiple candidate value need to be updated, then you have to use checkbox with name as `array` type.

**Updated Code:**

```
<html>
    <center>
        <font size="2" face = "century gothic">
        <?php
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","election2016");
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
        ?>
        <form method="post" action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
            <?php
            $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM candidate_info");
            echo "<table border='1'>
                <tr>
                    <th>Candidate Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Vote</th>
                    <th>Number of Votes</th>
                </tr>";
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['candidatename'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['position'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td><input type='radio' name='candidateid' value='".$row['candidateid']."' ></td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['numberofvotes'] . "</td>";
                        $candidateID=$row['candidateid'];
                    }
            echo "</table>";
            mysqli_close($con);
            ?>
            <br>
            <br>
            <input name = "update" type = "submit" id = "update" value = "update">
        </form>
    </center>
    </font>
</html>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['update'])) {

    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = '';
    $candidateid = $_POST['candidateid'];
    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

    if(! $conn ) {
         die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    $candidateid = $_POST['candidateid'];

    $sql = "UPDATE candidate_info SET numberofvotes = 1 WHERE candidateid = '$candidateid'" ;
    mysql_select_db('election2016');
    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

    if(! $retval ) {
         die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo "Updated data successfully\n";

    mysql_close($conn);
}
?>
```