# Bar Graph using the Data from MySQL Database

Tags: php, html

Hello Everyone Good Afternoon
as of now here's what I've got

```
    Database: Election2016
    Table Name: Candidate_Info
    Here is the 2 of my fields in my Table that I think is important in creating my Output 
candidatename[varchar] and numberofvotes[integer]
```

as of now heres my data

```
candidatename numberofvotes
Person1            24
Person2            1
```

From this Scratch How can i create a **Bar Graph?**
Im sorry for asking this easy question. Im only a beginner in this thing.

Im using PHP and it will be used in website
any help is appreciated TY

As of now here is my code

inside mysql_graph_bar.php

```
<?php
include("phpgraphlib.php");
$graph=new PHPGraphLib(550,350); 
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '')
   or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db('election2016') or die('Could not select database');

$dataArray=array();

//get data from database
$sql="SELECT * from candidate_info group by position";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
if ($result) {
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $salesgroup=$row["salesgroup"];
      $count=$row["count"];
      //add to data areray
      $dataArray[$salesgroup]=$count;
  }
}

//configure graph
$graph->addData($dataArray);
$graph->setTitle("candidates");
$graph->setGradient("lime", "green");
$graph->setBarOutlineColor("black");
$graph->createGraph();
?>
```

inside bargraph.php

```
<html>
<h3>This is where I want to display my graph</h3>
<img src="mysql_graph_bar.php" />
</html>
```

Comment: *Well, have you tried anything ?* If not, then please goggle few php code for bar graph. Use that code. Any problem comes, feel free to ask. Don't mind. See what happens is : As you will start searching answer and using it to your code, you will face few errors. Untill you fall, you will not rise.

Comment: You can go through it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29697351/unable-to-fetch-data-from-database-to-script-tag-while-using-graph

Comment: @NanaPartykar sir any codes would be a great help, seriously i dont now how to make it even if i search code. :( im sorry sir :(

Comment: This is the best site for all graphs type of stuffs. Go through it dear. Don't worry & Please don't hesitate. http://phpchart.com/examples/complete-phpchart-examples/ Choose any of the example. See how you exactly want. *Repeatedly saying, throw that fear*. Lot to achieve.

Comment: Sir i will try this one and ask question to this day TY sir

Comment: No Problem . Use It. Whenever you feel that without help you can't proceed further. *Ask Here*. There are many people here in Stack Overflow to help such. But, keep in mind. Here, people help to those who first try from themselves. *All The Best*

Comment: Instead of using PHPGraph, why don't you try **CSS3** bar chart? See this example link. [creative-punch.net/2014/03/simple-animated-html5-css-jquery-bar-chart](http://creative-punch.net/2014/03/simple-animated-html5-css-jquery-bar-chart/)

Comment: Sir it looks like hard for me, can you help me how to do that? give me some code if its ok with you sir, TY